# Closure isn't Send even though it only captures Send variables

Tags: rust

I have the following Rust code (rustc 1.75.0) which "forces" a type to be Send:

```rust
struct ForceSend<T>(T);
unsafe impl<T> Send for ForceSend<T> {}

pub fn perform<T>(t: T) {
    let wrapped = ForceSend(t);
    takes_send(move || {
        wrapped.0;
    });
}

fn takes_send<F: Send>(_: F) {}
```

I expect this code to compile, because the closure captures a single value `wrapped` by move, and this value is Send. Per [the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/closure.html#other-traits):

> A closure is Send if all variables captured by non-unique immutable reference are Sync, and all values captured by unique immutable or mutable reference, copy, or move are Send.

However this fails to compile, reporting that the closure is *not* Send.

Why does this not compile? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Based on whatever led you to this question, you might find the [`SendWrapper` crate](https://docs.rs/send_wrapper/latest/send_wrapper/) to be useful, especially when trying to coordinate sharing resources across threads from a library that is fundamentally single-threaded. `SendWrapper` similarly implements `Send` for any type but panics if you access the contained value from any thread but the original. This helps to e.g. force you to send things back to the original thread when you really need to access them (or drop them).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`wrapped.0` moves just the field `.0` from `wrapped`, and that field's type is T (non-Send). This would normally be useful for [partial moves](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/scope/move/partial_move.html) where you get to move-capture a subset of fields, and keep the remainder of the fields as not-moved.

In this case, you'll have to ensure that you move the *entire* `wrapped` object, e.g. by creating a binding that moves the entire `Wrapped` into the closure:

```
struct ForceSend<T>(T);
unsafe impl<T> Send for ForceSend<T> {}

pub fn perform<T>(t: T) {
    let wrapped = ForceSend(t);
    takes_send(move || {
        let w = wrapped;
        w.0;
    });
}

fn takes_send<F: Send>(_: F) {}
```

<sup>[[playground]](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=617068a47c564a7e93f36d9d0c788394)</sup>

On an unrelated note, if `T` is indeed unrestricted, this code is potentially unsound and may cause UB if `takes_send` really does want to send things across threads. For example, some operating system implementations of mutexes/related will malfunction if released from a different thread than the acquiring thread, and sending a `MutexGuard` across threads can produce that sort of scenario.

---

As an aside, here's an example of partial move behavior during capture in a more helpful situation:

```
pub struct Foo(String, String);

pub fn perform(t: Foo) {
    takes_closure(move || {
        t.0
    });
    
    takes_closure(move || {
        t.1
    });
}

fn takes_closure<F: FnOnce() -> String>(_: F) {}
```

<sup>[[playground]](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ee4c98c94dde25ad6cc42882ab5cc447)</sup>